# Oauth: how to handle form data when the server does a 302 to the Oauth provider

Tags: post, oauth, redirect

I have a simple application that has a textform at /edit.  That page has a "save" button that submits the post form to the server.

If the user's Oauth token has expired when they hit the save button, they will be redirected to a Oauth provider to sign in or get a refreshed token.

The Oauth server will then redirect them to a specific URL defined for the application.  Because the redirection will be a 302, no post data will be retained.

What is the most common way for the client to handle this so that the post data is not lost and can then be resubmitted once they are redirected back to the application?